# Python copy a DLL to site-packages on Windows

Tags: python, windows, dll

I am writing a python extension module that needs to link with a third-party DLL. How can I copy this DLL to the site-packages directory using distutils (i.e. in my setup.py file)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your DLL in the `package_data` argument of your `setup()` (see the [Installing Package Data](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data) section of the distutils documentation for details).

If you need to put the DLL outside of the package directory , you can use the `data_files` option. For example to put it in the `site-packages` directory:

```
import distutils.sysconfig

setup(
    # [...]
    data_files = [(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(), ["/path/to/the/DLL"])],
)
```

Comment: thanks. I want the DLL to get copied to the root level of site-packages, not into a package-specific subdirectory. Is there a way to do that using package_data?

Comment: The `data_files` option lets you put files anywhere you like, see the section 2.7 of the documentation I linked.

Comment: Another convenient piece of knowledge: Set the directory to an empty string to have the file installed in the package folder, e.g. `''` instead of `(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib()`

Comment: How to provide the relative path to the .dll?