# Add a dll/so to a python built distribution

Tags: python, dll, setuptools, nanomsg

I've compiled the [**python wrapper**](https://github.com/tonysimpson/nanomsg-python) of `nanomsg` and I want to create a python installer for the package.
The package can be created by running

```
python setup.py bdist --format=wininst
```

However I would like `nanomsg.dll/nanomsg.so` to be included in the installer/package but I haven't found any documentation regarding this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822424/python-copy-a-dll-to-site-packages-on-windows

Answer (score 12):

As stated in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) one needs to add the following code to his **`setup.py`** script:

```
setup(
    name='nanomsg',
    version=__version__,
    packages=[str('nanomsg'), str('_nanomsg_ctypes'), str('nanomsg_wrappers')],
    data_files=[(
        'lib\\site-packages\\', ["C:\\Dev\\external\\nanomsg\\x86\\Release\\nanomsg.dll"]
    )],
)
```

Comment: How to give the relative path of the dll?

Comment: @a11apurva see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980479/python-ctypes-loading-dll-from-from-a-relative-path