# How to make python package refer to packaged, non-python executable (.exe); Windows

Tags: python, windows, package, cygwin, executable

I am putting together a Python package that uses a Cygwin executable without having Cygwin installed. This means that I have an executable (`.exe`) file and a library (`.dll`) file inside my package. I am doing this so that the tool can be used on Windows by people who only use Windows and Python. I am new to Python packages, so I appreciate any help.

---

#### The Main Question

How do I make my package point to the executable file inside my package? This would be used, for example, instead of the executable referenced by `PATH`. The answer might be out there, but all I've found in my search is a bunch of info on how to create an executable from a Python script, which is NOT what I want.

---

#### Details/My Attempts

The tool is `sclite`, a tool to score speech recognition output. For information about how I get the tool available on Windows, have a look at the *How to Install SCLITE (for reproduce-ability)* section, below.

Here's a small, "toy" example of how I have my package set up.

```
$ tree package_holder_dir/
package_holder_dir/
├── bbd_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── non_py_exe_dll
│   │   ├── cygwin1.dll
│   │   └── sclite.exe
│   ├── score
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── run_sclite.py
│   └── score_transcript.py
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.txt
└── setup.py

3 directories, 9 files
```

My first guess was that the `sclite.exe` should go in the `MANIFEST.in` file.

```
# @file MANIFEST.in

include ./README.txt
include ./bbd_package/non_py_exe_dll/sclite.exe
include ./bbd_package/non_py_exe_dll/cygwin1.dll
```

I also tried putting them in `setup.py`

My `setup.py` is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# @file setup.py
    
import setuptools
from distutils.core import setup

with open ("README.txt", "r") as fh:
  long_description = fh.read()

setup(
  name='bbd_package',
  url='user@host.com',
  author='bballdave025',
  author_email='not.likely@idontwantspam.com',
  packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
  #data_files=[('lib', ['./non_py_exe_dll/cygwin1.dll']),
  #                     './non_py_exe_dll/sclite.exe'],
  version='0.0.1',
  description="Example for SO",
  long_description=long_description,
  include_package_data=True
) ##endof:  setup
```

Note [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33235543/6505499) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20151130052250/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216691/add-a-dll-so-to-a-python-built-distribution)) for my use of `data_files` for the location of the `DLL`. However, I could not find the files when I installed the distribution elsewhere. That's why they are commented out here.

Using `MANIFEST.in` seemed to work, but then I had to use a relative path to access the executable. That won't work when trying to `import bbd_package` in another directory.

Let me try to illustrate with my two Python files:

`score_transcript.py` simply calls `run_sclite.py`.

```
#!/usr/env/bin python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# @file run_sclite.py

import os, sys, subprocess

def run_sclite(hyp, ref):
  subprocess.call(['../non_py_exe_dll/sclite.exe', '-h', hyp, '-r', ref, '-i', 'rm', \
                   '-o', 'all snt'])
```

I can install it on my system:

```
C:\toy_executable_example\package_holder_dir>pip install .
```

Then if I happen to be in the directory with `run_sclite.py`

```
C:\toy_executable_example\package_holder_dir\bbd_package\score>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bbd_package.score.run_sclite
>>> bbd_package.score.run_sclite.run_sclite('a.hyp', 'a.ref')
sclite Version: 2.10, SCTK Version: 1.3
...output that shows it works...
>>>
```

However, from any other directory, no dice.

```
C:\Users\me>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit 
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bbd_package.score.run_sclite
>>> bbd_package.score.run_sclite.run_sclite('a.hyp', 'a.ref')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\dblack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bbd_package\score\run_sclite.py", line 9, in run_sclite
    '-o', 'all snt'])
  File "C:\Users\dblack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\dblack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\dblack\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>>
```

***How can I tell Python to look for the executable inside my package?***

---

#### System Details

This information is taken from running `systeminfo` from Window's Command Prompt.

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.15063 N/A Build 15063
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Member Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

---

#### How to Install SCLITE (for reproduce-ability)

I'm including a link to the installation instructions (using Cygwin) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50283077/6505499), look for my comment. Here are the commands with no explanation

```
$ cd
$ git clone https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi.git
$ cd kaldi/tools
$ extras/check_dependencies.sh
$ make -j $(nproc --all)
$ cp -R sctk-2.4.10 ~/
$ cd
$ rm -rf kaldi
$ cd sctk-2.4.10/
$ cp $HOME/.bashrc "${HOME}/.bashrc.$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S).bak"
$ echo -e "\n\n## Allow access to sclite, rfilter, etc" >> $HOME/.bashrc
$ echo 'export PATH='"$(pwd)/bin"':$PATH' >> $HOME/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

I'm also including a [link](http://www.voxforge.org/home/forums/message-boards/speech-recognition-engines/can-nists-sclite-be-used-on-windows/6#idQ6d5ISrRjCAgALRzU3E-OA) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20121023051703/http://www.voxforge.org/home/forums/message-boards/speech-recognition-engines/can-nists-sclite-be-used-on-windows/6)) to "quicker" instructions and the information about the `EXE` and `DLL` files. This is all thanks to @benreaves

> Easier (but even uglier) workaround, which I gave to an intern who did
> some Word Error Rate calculations for me:
>
> On my laptop with Cygwin installed, I create `sclite.exe` using my
>
> ```
> cp src/*/*.c . ; make all
> ```
>
> workaround from my previous message
>
> I create a zip file containing `sclite.exe` and `cygwin1.dll` from my
> laptop's `c:/cygwin/bin/` folder
>
> Email that zip file to her, and she copies both files in a single new
> folder on her laptop <s>and `set PATH=.;%PATH%`</s>

I don't set the `PATH`, because I want this to be distributible.

> This worked just fine on her laptop running Windows 7, and she didn't
> need Cygwin or any other NIST software on her laptop.
>
> -Ben

Comment: It seems that the Jupyter package places executables in the same folder as python.exe, that also seems a valid approach (but I don't know how to actually do that).

Comment: I've never tried it with Jupyter, @Jens_Wagemaker, but it's definitely worth looking at. Thanks.

Comment: With the data_files parameter in setup.py you can copy .exe and .dll to the scripts folder of a python virtual environment. (The scripts folder is added to the path environment variable when the venv is activated.) However the copy doesn't work when you only do an editable install, which was a show stopper for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work. The sources which I patched together are below. The basic answer is that I used the `__file__` variable to find the directory from which the packaged module was called, then used relative paths to get to my executable. I'm not really satisfied with this solution ([here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/10/29/python-101-how-to-find-the-path-of-a-running-script/) {[archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20180930083955/https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/10/29/python-101-how-to-find-the-path-of-a-running-script/)} are some situations in which it won't work), but it gets the job done for now.

#### Specifics

The `MANIFEST.in` file stayed the same:

```
# @file MANIFEST.in
# @author bballdave025

include ./README.txt
include ./bbd_package/non_py_exe_dll/sclite.exe
include ./bbd_package/non_py_exe_dll/cygwin1.dll
```

However, I needed to add the following to the `exe`-running code. This is in `run_sclite.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
#...
path_to_here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path_to_pkg_root = Path(path_to_here).resolve().parents[1]
path_to_exe = os.path.join(path_to_pkg_root, 'non_py_exe_dll')
#...
```

Note that Python version >= 3.4 is necessary for `pathlib`

Here is the whole (`run_sclite.py`) file:

```
#!/usr/env/bin python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# @file run_sclite.py
# @author bballdave025

import os, sys, subprocess
from pathlib import Path

def run_sclite(hyp, ref):
  path_to_here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
  path_to_pkg_root = Path(path_to_here).resolve().parents[1]
  path_to_exe = os.path.join(path_to_pkg_root, 'non_py_exe_dll')
  
  subprocess.call([os.path.join(path_to_exe, 'sclite.exe'), '-h', hyp, '-r', ref, \
                   '-i', 'rm', '-o', 'all snt'])
  
##endof:  run_sclite(hyp, ref)
```

---

#### Sources

[Mouse vs. Python](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/10/29/python-101-how-to-find-the-path-of-a-running-script/), with clarification on when this solution won't work and other alternatives. ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20180930083955/https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/10/29/python-101-how-to-find-the-path-of-a-running-script/))

[Getting to package root directory (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30218825/6505499) ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112000022/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218802/get-parent-of-current-directory-from-python-script/) ; Look for "Using os.path").

What finally got me to the answer:  [Python Packaging Tutorial](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html#first-admonition-title) . Look at the 'Note:'. ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20201107185002/https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html))