# What is the right way to specify a Windows-specific DLL install path in setup.py?

Tags: python, windows, pip, setuptools

I distribute a Python library that has wheels for OSX, Linux, and Windows. On Windows I have always included the DLLs using the `data_files` parameter to `setup()`. I copied this from an older package that I took over maintenance of, and it has always worked when I've tested it on Windows, but sometimes it doesn't work. I have no idea what the exact situation is that causes it not to work.

I recently [asked the pip devs](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10605) about why this was happening, and they said that the way I was specifying the file path was wrong, but they didn't know what the right way was. What is the right way to specify where DLLs should be installed in `setup.py`?

To be clear I am passing this value to `data_files`:

```
[("lib\\site-packages\\fugashi\\", [ ... build machine dll path ... ])]
```

This is kind of the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216691/add-a-dll-so-to-a-python-built-distribution) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822424/python-copy-a-dll-to-site-packages-on-windows), but the answer in both of those is to use `data_files`.

Comment: Use `package_data` instead of `data_files` which is unpredictable and unreliable. Smth like `package_data={'fugashi': ['lib/*.DLL']}`, then preload the DLL in Python code via e.g. `ctypes.CDLL(importlib.resources.path('fugashi', 'lib/mylib.dll'))`. Preloading isn't necessary on Unix with a `runtime_library_dirs` configured for the extension, but on Windows it doesn't work since not implemented in `disutils`.